# fd --exclude all except dir1 dir2

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, command, fd

`fd` searches files and directories, and can be called with `except` or `prune` as an option to limit the results.

Is there a way to search only for specified directories? I want to use `fd`, in `fzf`, and have the results always computed quickly (so the spinner stops spinning sooner).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the usecase - do you want to have`fd` already filter the results, instead of `fzf`? Do you want to use both to filter the results? `fzf`s filtering can potentially return more results than `fd` due to being a fuzzy filter. Do you accept that already filtering in `fd` would return less results?

Comment: I've edited the question and also resolved it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *excluding* or *pruning* all the directories except those I want to search through, I used the `--search-path` option to supply those directories; no need to exclude anything. Here's the configuration (in my `zshenv`):

```
# fzf
export CONFIGURATION="--search-path $HOME/.config --search-path $HOME/downloads --search-path $HOME/google_drive --search-path /etc"

export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="fd --type f --hidden --follow $CONFIGURATION . "
export FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND="$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND"
export FZF_ALT_C_COMMAND="fd --type d --hidden --follow $CONFIGURATION . "

_fzf_compgen_path() {
  fd --hidden --follow "$CONFIGURATION" .
}

_fzf_compgen_dir() {
  fd --type d --hidden --follow "$CONFIGURATION" .
}
```